# When I open the .py file nothing happens but it should print the predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

When I open the .py file nothing happens but it should print the predictions. Help?
This is the code. Sorry for my bad english.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

(test_loss, test_acc) = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

predictions = model.predict(test_images)

print(test_labels)
print(predictions)
```

Comment: Please explain how do you start the script.

Comment: I double click on the file on my computer

Comment: What **does** happen? Does the code open in an editor? Does a dos window open (and perhaps close again too quickly to see)?

Comment: A dos window opens but nothing happens, it just sits there

Comment: It either ends and closes or throws an error and closes, try adding sleep statements or run it on some terminal (command prompt using `python file.py`) it will show you errors or output properly.